# Can I edit a standard SAP app?

Tags: sapui5

So I've this question if it is possible to edit a standard app on SAP.

I'm currently building an app based on this [one](https://www.build.me/splashapp/gallery/project/1268).

And I wonder if after I downloaded and uploaded to Eclipse Mars I can edit it and upload it (again) to Fiori.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer your question
- Yes, you can edit it. In non S/4 systems you need a repair key to update the standard objects.

Warning: You should never do it unless in an exceptional case. Rather you should extend the Fiori app as Henning pointed.